# Vaadin 8.1 SCSS error by default: "Cannot resolve directory 'valo'" & "Error:(1, 18) Cannot resolve file 'valo.scss'"

Tags: css, import, vaadin, vaadin8

In a Vaadin 8.1.5 app created with the Maven archetype named `vaadin-archetype-widget` where I briefly the file in the demo app module > src > main > webapp > VAADIN > themes > demo > styles.scss, I get these errors reported by IntelliJ 2017.2:

> Error:(1, 13) Cannot resolve directory 'valo'
>
> Error:(1, 18) Cannot resolve file 'valo.scss'

…regarding this content:

```
@import "../valo/valo.scss";

$gray: #d1d1cf;
$green: #40b527;
$darkgreen: darken($green, 30%);
…
```

Is this a real error?

- Is that line a remnant of previous versions of Vaadin?
- Or do that `valo` folder and `valo.scss` file appear at build time, so not a real problem?

Even after building, perusing the `target` folder does not reveal an nested `valo` folder. I do see `target` > `my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT` > `VAADIN` > `themes` > `demo` > `styles.scss`. This leads me to believe this may be a mistake left in the Maven archetype's artifacts from previous versions of Vaadin.

Comment: Is that valo folder on classpath? Usually in some themes JAR file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no real error, this is IntelliJ not getting the big picture here (or like any IDE in most cases).  The authority of right or wrong here is the SASS-Compiler of Vaadin (which is either ran on request while in dev mode or by your build tool) and that will look up things on the classpath, while IntelliJ will try to find those on the actual directories.

That nested `valo` folder will be found at runtime in the `com.vaadin:vaadin-themes` jar.

Comment: I added a paragraph to the Question explaining that I do not find any nested `valo` folder in the built target.

Comment: Those directories are in the `com.vaadin:vaadin-themes` jar.